# If $ A_{k} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}\cos\left[\frac{k(k-1)\pi}{2}\right]\;,$ Then $\sum^{101}_{k=1}A_{k}=$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $\displaystyle A_{k} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}\cos\left[\frac{k(k-1)\pi}{2}\right]\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \sum^{101}_{k=1}A_{k}=$

$\bf{My\; Try:}$ Let $\displaystyle S = \sum^{101}_{k=1}A_{k} = A_{1}+A_{2}+A_{3}+........+A_{101}$

So we get $$\displaystyle S = 0\cdot \cos (0)+1\cdot \cos \left(\pi\right)+3\cdot \cos(3\pi)+6\cdot \cos (6\pi)+10\cdot \cos(10\pi)+.....+5050\cos(5050\pi)$$

Now I did not Understand How can I solve it

Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the more general problem:
$$A(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{k(k-1)}2\cos\Bigl(\frac{k(k-1)}2\Bigr).$$
Observe first that $\;\dfrac{k(k+1)}2- \dfrac{k(k-1)}2=k$. As $\cos\dfrac{k(k-1)\pi}2=1$ if $k=1$, we deduce that $\cos\dfrac{k(k-1)\pi}2=(-1)^{k-1}$, and the sum is simply, grouping in consecutive pairs of indices:
\begin{align*}
A(n)&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k(k-1)}2=\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k(k-1)}2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\biggl(-\frac{2j(2j-1)}2+\frac{(2j+1)2j}2\biggr)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}2j=\color{red}{n(n+1)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: There's a missing summation on the next-to-last line of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
\cos\left(\frac{k(k-1)\pi}2\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
1&\text{if }k\equiv0,1\pmod{4}\\
-1&\text{if }k\equiv2,3\pmod{4}
\end{array}\right.
$$
For the sum of four consecutive terms, we get
$$
\small\frac{(4k+1)4k}2-\frac{(4k+2)(4k+1)}2-\frac{(4k+3)(4k+2)}2+\frac{(4k+4)(4k+3)}2=2
$$
Therefore, the sum
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{k(k-1)}2\cos\left(\frac{k(k-1)\pi}2\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{24}2\\
&=50
\end{align}
$$
Adding the term for $k=101$, which is $5050$, yields
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{101}\frac{k(k-1)}2\cos\left(\frac{k(k-1)\pi}2\right)=5100
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $n$ is even, $cos(n\pi)=1$ and If $n$ is odd, $cos(n\pi)=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$\frac{k(k-1)}{2}=1+2+3+ \ldots +(k-1) = \sum_{r=1}^{k-1} r = S_{k} (say)$$

And since sum of an even and an odd number is odd while sum of two odd numbers is even, we have that:

$ S_2,S_3, S_6 ,S_7, S_{10}, S_{11} \ldots S_{4k+2},S_{4k+3} $ are all odd and they are $50$ in number. Similarly, $ S_1,S_4, S_5 ,S_8, S_9, S_{12}, S_{13} \ldots S_{4k+4},S_{4k+5} $ are all even and they are $51$ in number.

So if noted carefully, your sum can be expressed as the sum of $$\sum_x x \cos (x\pi) = \sum_x t_x$$

When $x$ is odd, $t_x=-x$ and when $x$ is even, $t_x=x$

So your sum boils down to $$\sum_{k=0}^{24}(S_{4k+4}+S_{4k+5})-\sum_{k=0}^{24}(S_{4k+2}+S_{4k+3})+S_{1}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{24}(S_{4k+4}+S_{4k+5}-S_{4k+2}-S_{4k+3})+S_{1}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{24}(4k+3+4k+3+4k+2)+0$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{24}(12k+8)$$
$$=6 \cdot 25 \cdot 24 + 8 \cdot 25$$
$$=3800$$

Hope this helps you. And ignore the calculations if there is any mistake in calculations.